# Can rdpmc be used to read the fixed-function counters on AMD?

Tags: x86, intel, performancecounter, amd-processor, intel-pmu

On Intel the fixed-function performance counters can be read by setting bit `30` of `ecx` as well the index of the counter to read (0-4) in the bottom bits of that same register.

Is something similar possible on AMD CPUs?